# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress redirecting post requests to GET

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I deployed a Ingress without certificate

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-dev-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: api.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80
```

It worked smoothly but without TLS.

Then, I installed cert-manager by Helm

`helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace --version v1.8.2 --set installCRDs=true`

And deployed a certificate just like below:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

    email: email@email.com

    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod

    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

and then redeployed the NGINX ingress with the tls attribute:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
  name: api-dev-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.dev
      secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: api.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Now I have my certificated ingress but the problem is that it's redirecting all requests to GET. I have a POST endpoint and when I run it, it's saying that it's not working.

[image: not working]

The log stats for ingress pod is this:

```
10.106.0.3 - - [12/Jul/2022:13:17:17 +0000] "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0" "-"
10.106.0.3 - - [12/Jul/2022:13:17:17 +0000] "GET /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 404 73 "http://api.dev/auth/login" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0" "-"
```

So maybe it's something related to this 301 redirect. Maybe it should be 308 but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this question marking this option on Postman[image: postman answer]

But I still don't know why.