# kubernetes and kong ingress redirecting post request to get - why and how do I change this behaviour?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I am in a strange situation I cannot understand how to debug.

In an enterprise, I am given a company-managed Kubernetes cluster.

I created a load-balancer for this cluster so that it is accessible inside the company on the domain name https://mydomain.company.com

Then `helm repo add kong https://charts.konghq.com` and `helm repo update` and then fetched an untarred **kong/kong** in a directory name `kong-helm` and then ran the command

```
helm upgrade --install --set ingressController.installCRDs=false -n kong --create-namespace kong kong-helm/kong
```

Everything looks good. everything works. Everything works fine. for example, I have a deployment like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "43"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: canary-mktplc-catalog
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  labels:
    app: canary-mktplc-catalog
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: canary-mktplc-catalog-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: canary-mktplc-catalog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: canary-mktplc-catalog
      name: canary-mktplc-catalog
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ******
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: canary-mktplc-catalog
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
```

and a service like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: canary-mktplc-catalog
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-10T18:58:23Z"
  labels:
    app: canary-mktplc-catalog
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: canary-mktplc-catalog-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.109.168.243
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.109.168.243
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: canary-mktplc-catalog
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and an ingress resource like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: canary-mktplc-catalog
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  labels:
    app: canary-mktplc-catalog
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: canary-mktplc-catalog-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: canary-mktplc-catalog-service
            port:
              name: http
        path: /api/mktplc-catalog
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.110.25.146
```

Using postman:

- sending a get request to `https://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog` returns "Hello World I received a get request"
- sending a get request to `http://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog` returns "Hello World I received a get request"
- sending a post request to `https://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog` returns "Hello World I received a post request"

But ....

- sending a post request to `http://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog` returns "Hello World I received a get request"

**The last one is turned into a get request. It is very strange and do not know how to debug it.**

Another observation is that these two both return the correct response

another observation is these two both return the correct response

- `curl --location --request POST 'http://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog'`
- `curl --location --request POST 'https://mydomain.company.com/api/mktplc-catalog'`

I found a similar question here

[Kubernetes NGINX Ingress redirecting post requests to GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952942/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-redirecting-post-requests-to-get)

the same solution worked for me. I turn on this setting it will return the correct response

[image]

And the [solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56226676/11065874) did not work for me because I already have the host hardcoded